# Write R code in a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

Is it possible to write R Code within the shiny app while it's running?  I've built a shiny app, but would like to give users the option to write their own R code in the shiny app. I want to put the console in shiny along with the viewer and a simplified environment pane.  I've never seen anything like this, so before I spend a lot of time doing this I'm wondering if it's even possible.  Has anyone seen something like this?

Thanks to Cory I found rfiddle, which is exactly what I'm looking for.  However I can't seem to get it to work. I used the iframe that r-fiddles website says to use to embed rfiddle, but I keep getting this error message:

```
Error in withReactiveDomain(shinysession, { : 
  No handler registered for for type .clientdata_output_<iframe width="300" height="600" src="http://r-fiddle.org/#/embed/eYsWfghB/1" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>_hidden
```

### Code:

```
library(shiny)
ui = shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
           htmlOutput(tags$iframe(width=300, height=600,
                                  src='http://r-fiddle.org/#/embed/eYsWfghB/1',
                                  allowfullscreen='allowfullscreen', frameborder='0'))

  )
)

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

})

shiny::shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Something like this?  http://www.r-fiddle.org/

Comment: Be aware of the security risk as R code can be used to access any files and services.

Comment: @cory That's perfect, but I'm not very good with html/css/js and I can't get it to work

Comment: Just remove `htmlOutput` and it will work. You'll want to increase the iframe width though.

Comment: Thanks, that works!  I just had to open it in a browser.

Comment: @XiongbingJin do you have a suggestion of how these security issues can be accounted for and avoided (while still achieving the OP's goal)?

Comment: Have you considered `shinyAce` package? See hello world example https://starkingdom.shinyapps.io/shinyAce-01-basic/